# Windows Form mover la barra de navegación

Tags: c#

Deseo mover la barra de navegación hacia bajo que se encuentra a la derecha de mi Windows Form con código de c#

**¿Sera posible?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿La barra de navegación es del control WebBrowser?

Comment: Si es la del control WebBrowser

Comment: ¿Mover como un scroll hasta el final de la pagina? o ¿Cambiar la barra de ubicación en la pantalla?

Comment: Si moverlo hacia abajo

Comment: @Diego, puedes revisar la respuesta que he publicado, o busca en Google: `c# winform webbrowser remove scroll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré una manera de hacerlo, no se si es la mas elegante de todas pero funciona, lo que hace básicamente es esperar que finalice de cargar la pagina, para desplazarse hacia abajo simulando mover la rueda del mouse, si el punto del mouse esta fuera del form lo posiciona dentro y luego hace que vuelva a su posición original, ya que si hace el desplazamiento estando fuera no funcionaria

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WebBrowserMoverBarraDesplazamiento
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800;

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Almacenamos la posicion actual del mouse
            int x = Cursor.Position.X;
            int y = Cursor.Position.Y;
            // Almacenamos las coordenadas del form
            int topForm = this.Top;
            int leftForm = this.Left;
            // Movemos el cursor del mouse para asegurarnos de que se posicione dentro del formulario
            Cursor.Position = new Point(topForm + 100, leftForm + 100);
            // Movemos la rueda del mouse hacia abajo
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, - int.MaxValue, 0);
            // Movemos el cursor del mouse a la posicion original
            Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);      
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Según [esta respuesta en Stack Overflow *en inglés*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11679043/4092887), puedes usar:

```
webBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
```

> **NOTA**: Revisa bien el contenido de aquella respuesta y has las pruebas
>   necesarias para lograr el funcionamiento deseado.